# Разница между '+' и ',' в методе System.out.println();

Tags: java

Часто замечал, что если я провожу какие-то математические операции с какой-то переменной, то вывести её с помощью

`System.out.println("integer: ", var);`

я не могу, разве что так:

`System.out.println("integer: ")`

`System.out.println(var);`

A с помощью

`System.out.println("integer: "+ var)`

делаю это без проблем. В чём разница между + и ,? Пробовал поискать что-то об этом, но либо плохо искал, либо такой глупостью никто не интересовался)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда пишешь запятую, ты перечисляешь передаваемые функции параметры. А так как сигнатура System.out.println() поддерживает лишь один аргумент (можно посмотреть в java doc какие именно. Кстати, есть сигнатура без аргументов), очевидно нельзя передать ей несколько параметров. А знак + это конкатенация строк (в println() автоматически у конкатенируемых объектов будет вызван метод toString()).

Comment: Кстати, вот нашел интересный пост про то как работает println() с примитивами https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024674/if-user-passes-a-primitive-type-argument-to-println-what-exactly-happens-behi

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно использовать [printf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)):

```java
printf("Hello %s!", "World"); //  "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Я думаю, человек спрашивал именно про специфику метода println().